# Is there a built in way in .Net AJAX to manually serialize an object to a JSON string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json, serialization, .net-2.0

I've found [`ScriptingJsonSerializationSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.scriptingjsonserializationsection.scriptingjsonserializationsection.aspx) but I'm not sure how to use it. I could write a function to convert the object to a JSON string manually, but since .Net can do it on the fly with the `<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>` and `<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()>` attributes so there must be a built-in way that I'm missing.

PS: using Asp.Net 2.0 and VB.Net - I put this in the tags but I think people missed it.

Comment: "using Asp.Net 2.0 and VB.Net - I put this in the tags but I think people missed it" - well, that "2.0" could be interpreted as "not 1.1" instead of "not 3.x".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
Dim jsonSerialiser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim jsonString as String = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(yourObject)
```

Comment: Note: in .NET 3.5 JavaScriptSerializer is marked as obsolete, it says to use DataContractJsonSerializer

Comment: In .NET 3.5 SP1, it is unobsolete again!

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're looking for is this class:

`System.ServiceModel.Web.DataContractJsonSerializer`

Here's an example from Rick Strahl: [DataContractJsonSerializer in .NET 3.5](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/218001.aspx)

Comment: Yes! You have no idea for how long I've been looking for this :)

Answer (score 4):

Since the JavaScriptSerializer class is technically being deprecated, I believe [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) is the preferable way to go if you're using 3.0+.

Comment: In .NET 3.5 SP1, it is unobsolete again!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am currently using the following extension methods to serialize and deserialize objects:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public static string ToJSON(this object objectToSerialize)
{
  JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  return jss.Serialize(objectToSerialize);
}

/// <typeparam name="T">The type we are deserializing the JSON to.</typeparam>
public static T FromJSON<T>(this string json)
{
  JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  return jss.Deserialize<T>(json);
}
```

I use this quite a bit - be forewarned, this implementation is a bit naive (i.e. there are some potential problems with it, depending on what you are serializing and how you use it on the client, particularly with DateTimes).

Answer (score 2):

In the System.Web.Extensions assembly, version 3.5.0.0, there's a [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class that should handle what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
```

or Check out [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) there is a whole list of libraries written to do exactly what you want.