# Create JSON with .net

Tags: .net, asp.net, json

First off, let me start off that I am not a .net developer. The reason why I am asking this question is that we rolled out our REST-API and one of our first integration partners is a .net shop.

So basically we assumed that .net would provide some sort of wrapper to create JSON, but the developer in question created the *string* by hand. I've researched this topic a bit and I couldn't really find anything, though I believe .net provides something. :)

```
'current code    
Dim data As String
data = "[hello, world]"
```

In PHP I would do the following (assuming ext/json is available ;):

```
<?php
$json = array('hello', 'world');
$json = json_encode($json);
```

I am also interested in what you use to decode the json into an array/object structure.

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a couple first-party and third-party options. [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/442969.aspx) has a good overview. [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) is the most popular third-party option.

Comment: This looks pretty good. I'll investigate this and will let you know. Thanks so far! (Sorry, I don't have any votes left right now. Regardless of what I'll choose, I will vote for this tomorrow.)

Answer (score 10):

See [Is there a built in way in .Net AJAX to manually serialize an object to a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-net-ajax-to-manually-serialize-an-object-to-a-json-s)

Which is to say, in .NET 2.0,

```
Dim yourData As String() = { "Hello", "World" }
Dim jsonSerialiser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim jsonString as String = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(yourData)
```

In .NET 3.5, send them to Rick Strahl's blog, mentioned above

Comment: I saw this, it doesn't actually answer my question though. Or maybe I don't get it.

Answer (score 7):

[Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) is an easy to use library with some cool features.

Answer (score 3):

[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) is very straight forward.

```
Person person = new Person();

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String json = serializer.Serialize(person);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm with Wayne - JSON.net works well.  The nice is, it works well with no learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx).

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer is much better since it requires less coding!