# How to use Json in asp.net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, json

Can someone please give some fair idea about how to use JSON?

Comment: can you be more specific?  What is your end-goal?

Comment: There are a lot of question on stackoverflow on this, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158818/create-json-with-net http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=datacontractserializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use JSON.NET (http://www.codeplex.com/Json) and I think it's a good library. The serialization is almost immediate:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

and vice versa:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there are no specifics, the best I can do is point you to a fairly complete how-to using .NET 3.5 to serialize an Object to JSON:

[.NET 3.5: JSON Serialization using the DataContractJsonSerializer](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Rick Strahl has written several excellent blog posts on the subject.

Try this post for starters: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/164419.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Heres a [Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/JSONSampleDotNet) of using JSON in ASP.NET.